# Syntax command error

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, syntax-error

Every time I run this .bat file it keeps on giving me a "syntax error command". Any idea on how to solved this?

```
if !numFiles! gtr 2 (
   gdal_merge.py -n 0 -a_nodata -32767 -of GTiff -o %out_path%\A!yearDay!.a1_file.file.tif !fileList!
   set "fileList=!fileList:~0,-1!"
   move !fileList: =,! "%proc_path%"
```

Comment: Run it with `@echo off` and it should hopefully tell you the exact line to look at.

Comment: Did that already and the "moving of files" part of the script is causing the error. How will I fix that part?

Comment: What system do you use? I've never seen statement like 'set "fileList=!fileList:~0,-1!"'. I think 'set "..."' statements make errors.

Comment: I'm using windows 7. How will I modify that part?

Comment: @Fumu, that's just stripping the last character off the string, it's valid from what I remember.

Comment: user, it should also have given you the pre-execute version of the line, so you should post the exact line where the error is occurring, the exact error text, and that pre-exec line.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're tyring to do with your move commands... It seems like you're trying to move multiple files at once which can only be done with wildcards, not individual filenames. So you may have to include a for loop to process the files to move. Syntax error is probably from move file1,file2,file3 destination - the commas would need protection like: "file1,file2,file3" if that is a real and just a single file name.

Comment: If I set the command to move with wildcards all the files will be moved even if there are some files that aren't processed yet. Those files that were processed only are the files that should be moved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, since you have narrowed your problem down to the following block:

```
if !numFiles! gtr 2 (
   gdal_merge.py -n 0 -a_nodata -32767 -of GTiff -o %out_path%\A!yearDay!.a1_file.file.tif !fileList!
   set "fileList=!fileList:~0,-1!"
   move !fileList: =,! "E:\Proc\Proc_Pro"
)
```

and `cmd.exe` doesn't identify the *specific* line in that block, you need to change it (temporarily) to isolate it to a specific line. Change the code section to:

```
if not !numFiles! GTR 2 goto xyzzy
  echo AAA xx!fileList!xx
  gdal_merge.py -n 0 -a_nodata -32767 -of GTiff -o %out_path%\A!yearDay!.a1_file.file.tif !fileList!
  echo BBB xx!fileList!xx
  set "fileList=!fileList:~0,-1!"
  echo CCC xx!fileList!xx
  echo DDD xx!fileList: =,!xx
  move !fileList: =,! "E:\Proc\Proc_Pro"
:xyzzy
```

Then run it with `echo on` again. Structuring this way will allow `cmd` to output individual lines before execution, rather than the entire `if` block.

This, and the added `echo` statements, should hopefully be enough to track it down.

---

Having performed those debug steps on some relevant test data, it boils down to basically this:

```
C:\USERS\pax\Documents>echo >qqq1
C:\USERS\pax\Documents>echo >qqq2
C:\USERS\pax\Documents>echo >qqq3
C:\USERS\pax\Documents>mkdir qqq
C:\USERS\pax\Documents>move qqq1,qqq2,qqq3 qqq
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

In other words, `move` does not permit you to move multiple comma-separated files to a destination directory, *despite the fact it appears to be possible according to the output of `move /?`.*

This is a known issue, which you can read about [here](https://superuser.com/questions/371302/cmd-move-move-a-couple-of-files).

You will need to find another way. Provided you can guarantee there are no spaces in the file names themselves (if there were, your original solution would not have worked anyway), you can use something like:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

rem Clean up first.
del /s qqq1.txt qqq2.txt qqq3.txt >nul: 2>&1
rmdir /s /q qqq >nul: 2>&1

rem Make the files and directories.
echo >qqq1.txt
echo >qqq2.txt
echo >qqq3.txt
mkdir qqq

rem Set up space-separated list.
set filelist=qqq1.txt qqq2.txt qqq3.txt

rem Move the files, this is the important bit.
for %%f in (!filelist!) do move %%f qqq >nul: 2>&1

rem Check it worked.
dir qqq

@endlocal
```

The bulk of that is test harness, the important bit is the line:

```
for %%f in (!filelist!) do move %%f qqq >nul: 2>&1
```

Comment: Tried to remove the `,` from the `move !fileList: =,! "%proc_path%"` and the syntax error command doesn't show up anymore but it shows a `The system cannot find the file specified.` error instead.

Comment: @user, that's because your command will now be `move file1.txtfile2.txtfile3.txt somewhere` - all you're doing is removing the spaces. You need to process the files one by one, I'll update the answer.

Comment: I've indicated the whole script I am using.

Comment: @user: see the last part of my answer, the bit beginning "Having performed those debug steps" - it states clearly what your problem is, and how to fix it.